# float.TryParse not working

Tags: c#

I created program that calculates the currency exchange rate.
The program has:

1. *ComboboxCurrencyName* - which displays the currency name.
2. *ComboCurrencyValue* - which displays the value of a given currency.
3. *txtYourValue* - textbox  which gets from user the amount of money
4. Button that calculates the rate of the given currency with the amount of money given from user.

My code:

```
public void EchangeRate(float x,float y)
{
    label1.Text = (x * y).ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(comboCurrencyName.SelectedIndex==comboCurrencyValue.SelectedIndex)
    {
        float currency;
        float inputValue;
        if(float.TryParse(comboCurrencyValue.SelectedItem.ToString(),out currency)&& float.TryParse(txtYourValue.Text,out inputValue))
        {
            EchangeRate(currency,inputValue);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not selected currency ");
    }
}
```

When I select a given currency with a combobox and I'm entering the value to convert, nothing happens when I press the button. I think this is a problem with converting combobox to float value.

Previously I used `float.Parse()` I had the error:

> System.FormatException: 'Invalid input string format.

[Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs7yN.png)

[image: Application window]

Comment: Your error `System.FormatException: 'Invalid input string format.` means that the string is not in the correct format for a float. So using `float.TryParse` means you will never get in that if statement (if your input still has the error) because it will return false.

Comment: The best way to do is to debug your application. Set a break point on the start of the button1_click and then press f11 to proceed. Use a try catch block to grab the exception. you should be fine

Comment: Add to the tryparse if statement `else MessageBox.Show("invalid input" );`

Comment: The MessageBox is displayed @YairHalberstadt

Comment: So what's the input? And what country are you in? (ie. What culture are you using?)

Comment: Have you tried using a comma instead of a decimal point?

Comment: My input is "1.1979" in comboCurrencyValue and "1000" in textbox("txtYourValue"). I'm from Poland.

Comment: I download the combobox data from the website "www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml". When changing from `float.TryParse ()` to `decimal.TryParse ()` It will not change anything

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace with:

```
(float.TryParse(comboCurrencyValue.SelectedItem.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out currency)&& float.TryParse(txtYourValue.Text,out inputValue))
```

To explain: in Poland a comma is used instead of a decimal point, so you must specify that you want to use an invariant culture.

Comment: I have a error: `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'result' of 'float.TryParse(string, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, out float)'`

Comment: The result is the last parameter (the currency). Are you sure you've got that correct?

Comment: Maybe there's a comma missing?

Comment: Ah. You probably used my answer before I'd edited it. Use the new one. Sorry

Comment: I added it: `if (float.TryParse(comboCurrencyValue.SelectedItem.ToString() , NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,out currency) && float.TryParse(txtYourValue.Text, out inputValue))` and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :-)